# Reading <property> tag

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I was asked today to look at a new project - reading in  some XML and doing some analysis.  I know a little C#.  I have gotten this far with this code that so far works.  I get the 4 node lists successfully.  I have a couple problems.  First I am not sure how to access what is in the  tag on any of the nodes in any of the lists.  Second, I'd prefer to be able to use LINQ queries but XmlNodeList doesn't seem to support that syntax.  In the sample XML below, I'd like to be able to get all the vdisks that belong to  a particular IO Group or mdisk  as determined by io_group_name or mdisk_grp_name property.  Most of what I looked at gave examples for accessing the [Attribute] list and searches all used properties/atttributes  interchanged.

What I tried is also below, it gave a null value exception.  The Attributes list only has one attribute.   I can't find any examples to do what I want and it isn't clear from inspecting the node in the debugger what I need to access to do what I want.

```
//this works

XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(_InputFile);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(reader);

XmlNodeList clusterlist = doc.SelectNodes("//object[@type='cluster']");
XmlNodeList controllerlist = doc.SelectNodes("//object[@type='controller']");
XmlNodeList mdisklist = doc.SelectNodes("//object[@type='mdisk']");
XmlNodeList vdisklist = doc.SelectNodes("//object[@type='vdisk']");


// this did not work - got null value exception
foreach (XmlNode vdisknode in vdisklist)
{
    string str = vdisknode.Attributes["mdisk_grp_name"].Value;
}
```

A sample of the XML:

```
<object type="vdisk">
     <property name="id" value="0" />
     <property name="name" value="nim01_vd06_gmt" />
     <property name="IO_group_id" value="0" />
     <property name="IO_group_name" value="ossvc06_iogrp0" />
     <property name="status" value="online" />
     <property name="mdisk_grp_id" value="0" />
     <property name="mdisk_grp_name" value="T1_OSIBM06_MDG1" />
     <property name="capacity" value="644245094400" />
     <property name="type" value="striped" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object` node has only one attribute: `type`

```
string type = vdiskNode.Attributes["type"].Value;
```

`property` node has two attributes: `name` and `value`:

```
string name = propertyNode.Attributes["name"].Value;
string value = propertyNode.Attributes["value"].Value;
```

---

What you need I deem is to extend the XPath query:

```
"//object[@type='vdisk']/property[@name='mdisk_grp_name']/@value"
```

---

Or use LINQ to XML:

```
from obj in doc.Load(xml).Root.Elements("object")
where (string)obj.Attribute("type") == "vdisk"
from prop in obj.Elements("property")
//where (string)prop.Attribute("name") == name
select prop.Value
```

Comment: vdisknode.Atttributes[] has one entry.  Name has string value of "type" and Value has sring value of "vdisk".   Your answer did help though.  I found what I wanted in vdisknode.ChildNodes

Comment: @DavidGreen: I guess `vdisknode.Atttributes[]` has one entry and it is `type`, correct? So yes indeed you need sub-nodes' (`property`) name and value.

Comment: @abatischev thanks for the assist with LINQ.  I came up with another version that works for XDocument, as per Stackoverflow, but yours will work for something else.